# ExpressJS: Requesting/Downloading xlsx file using express returning .txt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, npm, xlsx

My server side using Express JS

```js
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

module.exports = () => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      
      const data = [['1', '2', '3'],['4', '5', '6']];

      const filename = `Testing.xlsx`;

      const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);
      const merge = [
        { s: { r: 0, c: 0 }, e: { r: 0, c: 9 } },
        { s: { r: 1, c: 1 }, e: { r: 1, c: 7 } },
        { s: { r: 2, c: 1 }, e: { r: 2, c: 7 } },
        { s: { r: 2, c: 8 }, e: { r: 3, c: 9 } },
        { s: { r: 3, c: 0 }, e: { r: 4, c: 0 } },
        { s: { r: 3, c: 1 }, e: { r: 4, c: 1 } }
      ];
      ws['!merges'] = merge;
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Detail');
      const wbBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

      res.header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8');
      res.attachment(filename);
      return res.status(200).send(wbBuffer);
    } catch (error) {
      logger.log('error', 'DownloadSellerFinancialAccounts', { error });
      return next(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Meanwhile in the client site

```js
export function apiDownloadFinancilJournal() {
  return axios.get(`${paymentUrlApi.downloadFinancialJournal}`, { responseType: 'blob' });
}



apiDownloadFinancilJournal()
  .then((res) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8' }));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', `Financial-Journal.xlsx`);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: err.response?.data?.message ?? 'Server Error' });
  });
};
```

My question is, in which side I did it wrong? because the result is a txt instead of xlsx file. I have tried different type of stream data (blob, arrayBuffer, buffer) but the result is even worse

Comment: Why do you go through the hoops of using a blob and an object URL if you could just set the `paymentUrlApi.downloadFinancialJournal` as link URL directly?

Comment: they are in separate files so the code is more tidy. paymentUrlApi.downloadFinancialJournal is in constant, apiDownloadFinancilJournal is in API file, and and the code in the bottom is in the react component.

Comment: `const wbBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });`  Using 'buffer' as type which uses node buffer works fine on my end with Express.